# Play Framework Forms Type Mismatch When Upgrading to 2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

When upgrading my Play Framework from 2.3.6 to 2.4.8, I get this runtime error I request the first page.

```
type mismatch;
found   : play.api.data.Form[controllers.Account.PasswordData]
required: play.data.Form[controllers.Account.PasswordData]
```

Related to this line in my controller:

```
import play.api.data._

...

Ok(html.account.changePassword(passwordForm, "Change password", user))
```

And this line in my view (password.scala.html):

```
@(passwordForm: Form[controllers.Account.PasswordData], title: String, user: User)(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash)
```

Now it seems that Play uses play.data.Form when I import just use the term Form in the view.

What is the best way of fixing this? Should I hardcode play.api.data.Form into the view? Or change the Form object in Account.scala to play.data.Form?

And what is the difference between play.api.data.Form and play.data.Form?

Thank you!

Comment: Didn't replacing your import with this 'import play.data._'  fix your issue?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to do explicit imports in the template file. Still haven't seen if it works.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is some central place where the default imports are specified?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had accidentally configured play to use the Java API. In the Java API the Form class is play.data.Form but in the Scala API it is play.api.data.Form.

It was done in the build.sbt configuration on this line:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayEbean)
```

Comment: then you are doing a Scala project right? not Java?? I thought that it is Java. :)